# While Loop not printing second command

Tags: java, while-loop

Can anyone tell me why the second statement does not print when the counts gets below 4? The first part prints the "looping" part fine but it does not print "no more loops".  What's wrong?

```
enter code here

public class Scratchpad {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int xRay = 7;

    while (xRay > 4) {
        System.out.println("looping");

        if (xRay < 4)
            System.out.println("No more loops");
        xRay = xRay - 1;

    }

}
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Because your loop ends when xRay is less than 5

Comment: Move the decrementation of xRay above the if and change the condition to xRay <= 4

Answer (score 1):

When `xRay` reaches value 4, `while` loop finishes. That's why second statement doesn't get printed.

If you want to get it printed one solution would be this one:

```
public class Scratchpad {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int xRay = 7;

        while (xRay >= 4){
            System.out.println("looping");

            if(xRay <= 4)
                System.out.println("No more loops");

            xRay = xRay-1;

        }

    }

 }
```